# A field without the extension property

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

A field $\mathbb{K}$ is said to have the extension property if every automorphism of $\mathbb{K}(t)$ is an extension of an automorphism of $\mathbb{K}$, where $t$ is a variable. It is equivalent to the next property:

For every automorphism $\phi:\mathbb{K}(t)\rightarrow\mathbb{K}(t)$, $\phi(\mathbb{K})\subset\mathbb{K}$.

I think $\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ have the extension property. Do you know any field that does not have the extension property?

Comment: I would guess that $\Bbb{K}=\Bbb{Q}(u)$, $u$ another transcendental, would fit the bill. After all, interchanging $u$ and $t$ gives an automorphism of $\Bbb{Q}(u,t)$.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think you are right.

Comment: That is, as long as $u$ and $t$ are algebraically independent. When they were introduced as new variables I would think that was implied, but it is worth making sure.